# Как удалить определенный элемент item из XML? C#

Tags: c#, xml

Не удаляется элемент, может проблема в пути? Пытался удалить по id элемента, но в данной грамматике, у элемента item нет атрибута id, пытаюсь удалить по атрибуту weight, но снова не выходит. На этот раз ошибок нет, но удалять он все равно не хочет, может проблема в пути к этому элементу? Помогите пожалуйста..

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE grammar[
  <!ELEMENT grammar ANY>
  <!ELEMENT rule ANY>
  <!ELEMENT one-of ANY>
  <!ELEMENT item ANY>
  <!ATTLIST grammar version CDATA #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST grammar root CDATA #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST grammar tag-format CDATA #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST rule scope (public|private) #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST rule id ID #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST item id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="ru-RU" root="Подтверждение" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics-ms/1.0">
    <rule>
       <one-of>
       </one-of>
    </rule>
    <rule xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" id="имя" scope="public">
        <one-of>
          <item>Иванов<tag> $ = "Иванов"</tag></item>
          <item weight="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">Можаев<tag> $ = "Можаев" 
          </tag></item>
        </one-of>
      </rule>
</grammar>
```

```
static string grammarPathXML = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "UserGrammar.xml");  //путь к XML    ​
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(grammarPathXML);
       ​xdoc.Elements("rule").Where(att => att.Attribute("id").Value == "имя")
           ​.Elements("one-of")
           ​.Elements("item")
           ​.Where(att => att.Attribute("weight").Value == "1.0")
           ​.Remove();
       ​xdoc.Save(grammarPathXML);
```

Comment: Раз уж вы перешли на Linq2Xml, то удалите DTD - он всё равно не используется и считается устаревшим и вообще опасным (из-за возможности экспоненциального раскрытия сущностей - короче, всё намертво зависнет...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала я расскажу о инструменте, которым буду пользоваться во время ответа. Это Linqpad - легковесная мини-IDE для отладки небольших фрагментов кода.

Очень удобно смотреть небольшие запросы пользуясь методом расширения `.Dump()`: вот как выглядит ваш пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или например корневой элемент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или первая нода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или любой linq-запрос. Через некоторое время натренируетесь так, что будете из головы писать длинные linq-запросы без ошибок.

---

Ну и начнём разбирать ваш запрос с самого начала.

И в самом же начале видим, что ваш запрос не находит никаких нод rule:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всё, можно уже не искать никакую ошибку в коде далее, потому что уже НОЛЬ узлов, как их не фильтруй - ничего не найдёшь, новые не появятся. И вообще весь linq-код правильный, валидный, я проверил по структуре - всё верно. За одним исключением.

Вы не работаете с пространствами/неймспейсами XML. Прямо говоря -- типичная ошибка кто начинает работать с XML и особо документацию не читал.

Вот настоящее имя вашего элемента, вот так всё прекрасно находится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Взято из вашего же xml-файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, понятное дело так влоб никто не пишет. Если посмотрите [оф.доку](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=net-5.0) и примеры на stackoverflow (сходу что нашлось [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2340411/5752652)) то все используют переменную неймспейса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И постепенно двигайтесь в отладке вашего linq-запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так шаг за шагом - до конца:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и финально -- удаляете и сохраняете:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё!

Итого, на будущее, если хочется научиться разбираться самостоятельно, а не ждать помощи от коллег:

- научитесь отлаживать запрос шаг за шагом и находить первую точку в которой уже не работает;
- мало кто любит читать документацию и фундаментальные книги, особенно когда тебе презентуют технологию "хей, тут три строчки кода написать" (наша технология крутая и подходит для быстрого старта). За этот быстрый старт платят именно тем, что когда начинаются проблемы - надо лезть в доки, которые никто не хочет читать.

Comment: Вписал в ответ только самую главную ошибку, так-то ещё по мелочи есть. Во-первых, атрибут может быть null и вызывать на нём .Value - риск получать NullReferenceException. Во-вторых, стоит получать xdoc.Root, а потом уже делать запросы.

Comment: А, и ещё. Чтобы не хардкодить неймспейс - в вашем случае его можно получить программно: `var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();`

Comment: Спасибо! 
Да, я находил точку, в которой не работал код, и понимал, что он не может найти нужный элемент, но не мог понять почему. Спасибо большое!